# jasmine tests, how can I improve the performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using `jasmine` and `karma` for unit tests of my app, with approx. 1000 tests at the moment, it takes around 10 seconds until they're finished.

It's not a problem right now, but in a couple of months the number of tests might become much bigger and I'd like to know if there's anything I can do to make them run faster, at least locally.

I found out that using:

```
jasmine.any(Object)
```

is much faster than comparing big objects.

Changing:

```
expect(some.method).toHaveBeenCalledWith("xyz");
```

into:

```
expect(some.method.calls.argsFor(0)[0]).toBe("xyz");
```

also seems to be a little bit faster.

Karma is lovely but it doesn't seem to have anything that improves performance yet, it's really useful for debugging though (`reportSlowerThan`).

Any other ideas how can I improve the performance of the tests?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of performance improvements are you seeing in switching from `toHaveBeenCalledWith`?

I appreciate what you're trying to achieve – you have a test suite that runs 10 seconds and you're right to try and improve that situation – but if the savings are in < 500ms range I would be careful as the readability and clarity of your tests are put at risk.

`toHaveBeenCalledWith` communicates your intentions to others much better than the `argsFor` approach does, as does the message that would displayed if that test were to fail;

> Expected function to have been called with "xyz"

vs

> Expected undefined to be "xyz"

---

With that said, some ideas...

#### 1

Look for areas where you can safely replace `beforeEach` calls;

> The `beforeEach` function is called once before each spec in the describe in which it is called

With `beforeAll` calls;

> The `beforeAll` function is called only once before all the specs in describe are run.

But be careful not to introduce shared state between tests which could skew your results (using Jasmine's option to run the tests in a random order might help here but I'm not sure how `beforeAll` is handled by this, it could be that those specs are still run together).

#### 2

Continue using `reportSlowerThan` as you have been and pick off any that are *really* slow. If changes like the one you suggested are unavoidable, put them behind helper functions with well-chosen names so that what you're trying to achieve is still clear to other developers. Or better still, create Custom Matchers for them because that will also result in clear messages if the tests fail ([add-matchers](https://github.com/JamieMason/add-matchers) can help make this easier).

#### 3

Consider switching from Jasmine to [Jest](https://facebook.github.io), tests are written in pretty much the same way, but the test runner is much faster.